# Ngx-datatable wrongly in (component) HTML how do I sort table by column name with a dropdown box (Angular 7)

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-core, sass

I am needing to have a dropdown box that sits above a Ngx-datatable and that dropdown box needs to sort the Ngx-datatable by the values in the dropdown box.  I am still new to Angular, so as I discovered that it is wrong to have the ngx-datatable in the component.html.  How might I bootleg the datatable so that I can sort the rows by the values in the dropdown box?

Thinking that the method in the component.ts was linked to the datatable I was going to call that method in the dropdown box to sort it.  It is completely separate!

component.html

```
<ngx-datatable class="expandable"
                 [rows]="rows"
                 [columns]="columns"
                 [headerHeight]="40"
                 [rowHeight]="'auto'"
                 [columnMode]="'force'" [limit]="20" [footerHeight]="50">
    <ngx-datatable-column name="Header">
      <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <span class="custom-cell"><a (click)="method(content, id, false)">{{value}}</a></span>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
```

My dropdown box

```
<div ngbDropdown class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-light filter-button" id="input1" ngbDropdownToggle>Select an option</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="inputmethod">          
      <!--<select (change)="getColumnNames($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let element of rows" value="{{element.header}}"></option>
      </select>-->
```

component.ts

```
columns = [
{ prop: 'header', name: 'Header' },
{ prop: 'notrelavant', name: 'Not Relevant' }, ];
```

What I need is: On click of the header value in dropdown box sort the datatable.

Comment: How do you want it to be sorted? Alphanumerically? Or are they all string values (without any numbers)? Or just numbers?

Comment: @wentjun Sorted by the header column.  These will all be string values.  No numbers for now.  There may be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with a solution for yours. It is actually not very difficult if we break down the steps:

1) On the `ngbDropdown`, we populate the menu items with the columns of the datatable. we attach a `click` event binding on each individual menu items, and we bind them to the `sort()` method, which takes in the column property (`column.prop`) as a parameter.

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-light filter-button" id="input1" ngbDropdownToggle>Select an option</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="inputmethod">
    <button ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let column of columns" (click)="sort(column.prop)">
      {{ column.prop }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Now, on our component.ts, we define our `sort()` method. `rows` represent the data in the datatable. We use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
to sort it in alphanumerical order. We create a shallow copy of `rows` to explicitly trigger [change detection](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/change-detection) within the datatable to update the order of the data.

```
  sort(prop) {
    this.rows.sort((a, b) => a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop], 'en', { numeric: true }));
    this.rows = [...this.rows];
  }
```

I have created a working demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9fodl?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Hope it helps in my explanation!

Comment: How would you do it if you only wanted one column name only?